# how to classify Iris flowers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ai

I'm working on a classification problem .I want to classify Iris flowers from the famous Iris data set using MLP. I know that I the number of neurons in output layer should be the same number of classes but can I use one neuron in output layer which output is the value (0 or 1 or -1) to refer to the three types or then it is considered as regression not classification ???? thanks

```
trin= [4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2;
   4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2;
   5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4;
   5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1;
   5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2;
  5.7 2.6 3.5 1;
  5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1;
  5.5 2.4 3.7 1;
  5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2;
  6 2.7 5.1 1.6;
  6.7 3.3 5.7 2.1;
  7.2 3.2 6 1.8;
  6.2 2.8 4.8 1.8;
  6.1 3 4.9 1.8;
  6.4 2.8 5.6 2.1
  ];
   trout=[-1;-1;-1;-1;-1;
          0;0;0;0;0;
         1;1;1;1;1];
         inp=size(trin,2);
         out=size(trout,2);
          hidden=2;


      x=[-0.8000,-1.520,-0.9400,-3.040,3.800,2,-2,3.790,-1,0,4.600,4.400,0];
 iw = reshape(x(1:hidden*inp),hidden,inp);
 b1 = reshape(x(hidden*inp+1:hidden*inp+hidden),hidden,1);
 lw = reshape(x(hidden*inp+hidden+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out),out,hidden);
 b2 = reshape(x(hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+out),out,1);

 y =
```

tanh(tanh(trin*iw'+repmat(b1',size(trin,1),1))*lw'+repmat(b2',size(trin,1),1));
    e = gsubtract(trout,y);

is this classification or it is considered as regression . I mean should I make the out put 3 bits to be consedered as classification and how to do this if yes?

Comment: If you did that what would be your loss?

Comment: I don't know how to make the output three bits. I found this way(to make it one bit) easy but fall in trouble that it may considered as regression

Comment: And what about the loss you would use?

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: Maybe you should start looking at that, if the loss you want to use is cross entropy it is more like classification if the loss is like mean squared error it is is closer to regression.

Answer (score 1):

The iris dataset is meant to be used for classification. You have 3 separate classes of irises and attempting to solve it as a regression problem would be a mistake.

Think about your proposed solution, you want the output to be -1,0 or +1 (for classes a,b and c). But this implies that class a is more similar to class b than to c, and by the same principal that class c resembles class b more than a. You are adding a prior to the model that was not there before, and you should not do that (unless you are an iris specialist).

you need to take your class output labels and convert them to a one-hot-encoding representation:
class a = [1,0,0]
class b = [0,1,0]
class c = [0,0,1]

Then use categorical cross entropy for your loss function.

Comment: Do you have a useful links that help me doing this "Then use categorical cross entropy for your loss function."?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/